# css3 border-image firefox 15.0.1

Tags: firefox, css

We have a web ready for publish. It uses css3 border-image.
In previous version of firefox all ok, but with last update (firefox 15.0.1) doesn't work.

For testing:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_border-image

This example works with opera, chrome, safari and older versions of firefox.

How to repair this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `border-style: solid`.  It used to be that setting `border-image` overrode `border-style` settings, but that got changed in the spec, and the Firefox implementation was changed to follow he spec.

Comment: Your solution go ok, but not fill the body, only borders. Is this other change in specifications? How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Yes, that was another spec change.  If you want to fill the body as well, you need `border-image-slice: fill` or its equivalent in the `border-image` shorthand.  See http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-background/#the-border-image-slice