# css3 border-image firefox 15.0.1 (second round)

Tags: firefox, background, css

In reference to this question: [css3 border-image firefox 15.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385269/css3-border-image-firefox-15-0-1)

I resolve issues with new version of firefox (15.0.1) and now border-image feature go. But a new issue appears. Content is not filling with the image.

In all browsers the background is filling with the border image, except in new version of firefox.

My class:

```
border-style: solid none solid solid;
border-width: 12px 0 12px 12px;

border-image: url("img/contents-entry.png") 12 0 12 12 stretch; /* CSS3 recommendation */
-moz-border-image: url("img/contents-entry.png") 12 0 12 12 stretch stretch; /* old Firefox */
-o-border-image: url("img/contents-entry.png") 12 0 12 12 stretch; /* Opera */
-webkit-border-image: url("img/contents-entry.png") 12 0 12 12 stretch; /* Safari */

background-color: transparent;
```

Thanks

UPDATE:
This is my test in http://jsfiddle.net/angelcervera/8YWXs/ :

```
div {
border-width:15px;
width:250px;
padding:10px 20px;
background-color: red;
}

#round {
border-style: solid;
border-image:url("http://www.norabrowndesign.com/css-experiments/images/border1.png") fill 30 30 30 30 stretch;
-moz-border-image:url("http://www.norabrowndesign.com/css-experiments/images/border1.png") 30 30 30 30 stretch; /* Firefox */
-webkit-border-image:url("http://www.norabrowndesign.com/css-experiments/images/border1.png") 30 30 30 30 stretch; /* Safari */
-o-border-image:url("http://www.norabrowndesign.com/css-experiments/images/border1.png") 30 30 30 30 stretch; /* Opera */
}
```

I added:

- **background-color: red;** in div styles to distinguish the white background page from div background.
- **border-style: solid; border-image:url("border.png") fill 30 30 30 30 stretch;** in #round styles to work in firefox, but doesn't fill.
- I changed image with a no transparent image.

Comment: I edited with an example test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the other question, you need:

```
border-image: url("img/contents-entry.png") fill 12 0 12 12 stretch;
```

if you want to fill the central area of the box.  See http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#border-image-slice

Comment: Yes, this was my first test, but doesn't work. I update the question with test code. I supposed I didn't understand specification.

Comment: Your fiddle is setting both `border-image` and `-moz-border-image` but not including the `fill` in the latter.  They're aliases for each other, so the `-moz-border-image` overrides the `border-image`.  This is why you want to put the unprefixed property after all the prefixed ones, generally.